# Create thread via class constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, constructor, pthreads

Is it possible to create a thread with a function pointer to a class constructor?

If this is possible, when how would the class destructor get called?

I have made this example of what i am looking for:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(void* argPtr)
    { ... }
};

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &ClassA(), NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, a constructor is not a function; its address cannot be taken. `&ClassA()` (if it even compiles) creates a temporary object and takes an address of that.

Comment: You can create a thread that calls a function that creates an instance of `ClassA` and will call its constructor.

Comment: What you can do so have a thread created in your constructor which then runs on your object - not quite the same; and can end up with other cans of worms being opened (the object isn't yet constructed!)

Comment: You may want to look up `<thread>`. Pthreads are for C, and don't understand C++. And in modern C++, you _can_ call `std::thread(&std::make_unique<ClassA>).detach()`. Then the destructor will be called when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors are classified as "special member functions", and it is not possible to get a pointer to constructor function because it does not have a name (note that you are using class name, not a constructor function name, to invoke it):

> 12.1 Constructors [class.ctor]
>
> 1
>   Constructors do not have names.
>
> ...
>
> 2
>   A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type. Because constructors do not have names, they are never found during name lookup;

Also `pthread_create` takes a pointer to a regular function, not to a member function.